# Difference between using UINavigationController and UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

I started learning ios development recently. I made a project using `UINavigationController` by embedding it because I need a title bar. But I can achieve the same thing by using `UINavigationBar` from the object library.

The only difference I saw is when I use `UINavigationController` I get a back button when I use segue. Are there any more differences between them? Which one is used in which situations?

By the way, why another `NavigationController` is added to my storyboard? What is the significance of it?(No one explained about it in any video I have seen)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NavigationController` handles its own `UINavigationBar` automatically and also handles your navigation stack of viewControllers, The `NavigationController` has a delegate that you can use to know what is happening in your viewControllerNavigationStack and so forth

Using the delegate of `NavigationController` you can for example be notified when:

- The NavigationController will show some viewController, using this method :

  `- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated`;
- The NavigationController did show some viewController, using this method :

  ```
  - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
  ```

You can also use `NavigationController` to go into specific viewController on your navigation stack for instance, or you can pop and push viewController without segues

Comment: "The NavigationController has a delegate that you cant use to know what is happening in your viewControllerNavigationStack and so forth". Can you explain this more please?

Comment: @user6528991 my answer was edited to explain your comment, I hope this helps

Comment: he meant "can" not "cant" but you can't edit a question in SO untill you do 6 chars.

Answer (score 2):

The [`UINavigationBar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html):

> The UINavigationBar class provides a control for navigating
>   hierarchical content. It’s a bar, typically displayed at the top of
>   the screen, containing buttons for navigating within a hierarchy of
>   screens. The primary properties are a left (back) button, a center
>   title, and an optional right button. You can use a navigation bar as a
>   standalone object or in conjunction with a navigation controller
>   object.

The [`UINavigationController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934):

> The UINavigationController class implements a specialized view
>   controller that manages the navigation of hierarchical content. This
>   navigation interface makes it possible to present your data
>   efficiently and makes it easier for the user to navigate that content.
>   You generally use this class as-is but you may also subclass to
>   customize the class behavior.

**Using a Navigation Bar With a Navigation Controller**

> The most common way to use a navigation bar is in conjunction with a
>   UINavigationController object. **If you use a navigation controller to
>   manage the navigation between different screens of content, the
>   navigation controller creates the navigation bar automatically and
>   pushes and pops navigation items when appropriate.**
>
> A navigation controller automatically assigns itself as the delegate
>   of its navigation bar object. Therefore, when using a navigation
>   controller, don’t assign a custom delegate object to the corresponding
>   navigation bar

[image]